# Obtaining Selenium CSV download into python variable

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

When I run the below code, a chrome window opens, the page loads and a CSV file downloads into my documents.

However, I want to download the CSV file into a python list.

When I try to print the initial download it shows 'None' and reading in csv.reader shows the following error message:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def getData()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(f"http://financials.morningstar.com/balance-sheet/bs.html?t=AAPL")
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "rf_export")))
    data = button.click()
    print(data)
    data = csv.reader(button)
    for row in data:
        print(row)
    return data

getData()


-------------


None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helpers.py", line 403, in <module>
    newData2("AAPL")
  File "helpers.py", line 397, in newData2
    data = csv.reader(button)
TypeError: argument 1 must be an iterator
```

Comment: What do you mean by "download the CSV file into a python list" ?

Comment: I mean downloading into a python variable rather than to the local device.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at he download button on that page, it is a link to the following javascript function: `SRT_stocFund.Export()`

Looking at this function (at http://financials.morningstar.com/finan/static/script/SRT_stockFund.js), it calls `SRT_StockFund.GetPara()`, and uses the returned data to create a link, and changes your browser's location to it:

`document.location = hostPath+"/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?" + params+"&denominatorView="+denominatorView+"&number="+number;`

In my case, the url looked like this:

`"//financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=bs&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=13805&denominatorView=raw&number=3"`

What you could easily do in selenium is:

- call the `GetPara()` function
- create the download url yourself.

You can call javascript from within selenium with something like:
`driver.execute_script('SRT_stocFund.GetPara()')` - and then build your string to create the download link, and retrieve it.

Your browser's dev tools are your friend here.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time Danielle, I had explored the JS in an attempt to pull from the url alone but for some reason this doesn't work. Running `driver.execute_script('SRT_stocFund.Export()')` alone downloads the file. However, as with the above method, it downloads to my local device rather than into a python variable which is the requirement. Any ideas?

Comment: As per my comment, construct the URL, and then use python to download it, eg.: requests.get(the_url)

Comment: That is what my original program did. However, the site seems to have restricted use of the url. Hence my search for another option. Entering [your link](//financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&reportType=bs&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=5&curYearPart=1st5year&rounding=3&view=raw&r=13805&denominatorView=raw&number=3) no longer initiates a download :(

Comment: No, it needs to be generated every time, using selenium to grab the page and run the javascript to get the vars, and only then to build the ephemeral URL.

Comment: OK I get you! Code now includes `driver.execute_script(f'SRT_stocFund.LoadAComponent("sfcontent", "XNAS:AAPL", "bs", "", "SB", 10)')` followed by `driver.execute_script('SRT_stocFund.GetPara()')` then I try requests.get(my_url) but the value has gone from returning none to returning an empty array.